# Is it possible to hide behind a hostname to purposefully effect SEO?

Tags: attack-prevention

Reference forum questions and a couple answers posted on 10 December 2014

[What are these unknown visits to my private, unlisted webpage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/what-are-these-unknown-visits-to-my-private-unlisted-webpage/75764#75764?newreg=a5490846d15e4a7ebf443919b98a56e9)

One of the answers contained this phrase: "Given the fact that they are hitting your page with another host name..."

Here is my delimna.  I have 2 websites, one that is about 1.5 years old and the other that is about 6 months old.  The problem in the original question submitted is an item that I have seen on my sites, but in huge numbers.  So much so that it has caused my SEO to be nonexistent and I can no longer be found on google period. For example from 8 Dec till today, there were 46 of these sessions from Russia on just one site, the newest one.  It's almost as if someone is purposefully attempting to cause my bounce rate to be the 80 percent plus that it has become.

I don't even know how to approach this problem.

The older website, I haven't cared so much about as it was a website that I was putting together. I never really noticed or started studying the problem through Google Analytics until a month back, which caused me to go look at my other site. I started looking and and making some comparisons.  The behavior is the same and has been sustained and consistent and thus I have to believe it is somehow purposeful.  Is that possible?

I found this site because I typed in the service provider of "hosting telesystems network" in Moscow. This is just one example as I see other places in SE Asia showing the same behavior.  Again, consistent and sustained.  I need some help big time before I decide to build another site and run into the same issue.

Comment: Whoa, slow down. What problem are you exactly facing? What makes you think Google has penalised you? *cum hoc ergo propter hoc*

Comment: Good question!  The problem(s) is that at one time a search with a generic search and location specific phrase would bring my my website up anywhere from page 2-4 as the site (one of them) was relatively new.  If a search was done with just company name, it would show up on page one.  Now with the same search phrases (generic or not) it does not come up at all.  That is the same for both sites.  My reading on the subject of SEO and bounce rates indicates that Google will increasingly penalize a site that has high bounce rates.

Comment: It's very unlikely that this traffic does in any way affect your Google pagerank. There could be a million other reasons why Google doesn't list your website anymore. But this is a topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are the hits from a small set of locations? In particular, a smallish set of IP addresses?

If so, why not just block the connections?

I regularly get unsavoury connection attempts from various locations and I have scripts in place to auto-ban the IP addresses.

Indeed, depending on the nature of the site, you might be better off simply banning whole countries!

By banning, the originating IP cannot access the web site, doesn't trigger analytics and doesn't show up in any Google stats.